# How to call function webpackJsonp from browser console

Tags: javascript, webpackjsonp

I want to do automatic action on a website but their code has webpack. How can I call those functions?

```
"object" != typeof globalThis && (globalThis = window),
(this.webpackJsonp = this.webpackJsonp || []).push([[0], {
    BKWD: function(e, t, s) {
        "use strict";
        var h = new class {
            constructor() {
                ...
            }
            _WriteLog(e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

How to call function _WriteLog from browser console.

Answer (score 1):

U have 2 way.
First and right way - is export needed data from your entry file. For this. use Webpack Library, its basic functional of webpack.

`https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary`

1. Add library option to your webpack config:

```
 output: {
    library: 'MyLibrary',
  },
```

2. Export needed data from your main.js or another  js

```
export function hello(name) {
  console.log(`hello ${name}`);
}
```

3.. That function will be amiable in window.

```
<script>
MyLibrary.hello('webpack');
</script>
```

...

Second way, if u have no sources of webpack. Link the function. Create empty variable in file start, and link needed function after. For example:

```
var ssst;

"object" != typeof globalThis && (globalThis = window),
(this.webpackJsonp = this.webpackJsonp || []).push([[0], {
    BKWD: function(e, t, s) {
        "use strict";
        ssst = new class {
            constructor() {
                ...
            }
            _WriteLog(e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}]);


console.log(ssst)
```

Comment: It's a website that wasn't mine so I don't have the source code. How can I call these functions from the console chrome browser

Comment: U must find and link this function from file, like example ssst upper

Comment: How can I inject my code there?